# Shimmer animation not working on Jetpack Compose Android

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have created a Shimmer animation loader using Jetpack compose, but the animation is not working it's just showing the gradient.

Expected Shimmer Animation

[image]

Output from my code (not showing animation, it just shows gradient)

[image]

Here is the code for shimmer animation

```
fun Modifier.shimmerEffect(): Modifier = composed {
  var size by remember {
      mutableStateOf(IntSize.Zero)
  }
  val transition = rememberInfiniteTransition()
  val startOffsetX by transition.animateFloat(
    initialValue = 0f,
    targetValue = 2 * size.width.toFloat(),
    animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
        animation = tween(1000)
    )
  )

  background(
    brush = Brush.linearGradient(
        colors = listOf(
            Color(0xFFB5B5B5),
            Color(0xFFEBEBEB),
            Color(0xFFB5B5B5)
        ),
        start = Offset(startOffsetX, 0f),
        end = Offset(startOffsetX + size.width.toFloat(), size.height.toFloat())
    )
  ).onGloballyPositioned {
        size = it.size
    }
}
```

Here is the Composable function where shimmerEffect is applied

```
@Composable
fun ShimmerItem(modifier: Modifier = Modifier){
   Row(modifier = modifier) {
      Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(100.dp)
            .clip(CircleShape)
            .shimmerEffect()
      )
   }
}
```

Here is the code where the ShimmerItem is being used.

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(homeViewModel: HomeViewModel = koinViewModel()) {
    when (val state = 
           homeViewModel.screenState.collectAsState().value) {
        is HomeUiState.Success -> {
             HomeLayout(data = state.homeData)
        }
        is HomeUiState.Loading -> {
             ShimmerItem()
        }
        is HomeUiState.Error -> {}
    }
}
```

Here is the viewModel code

```
private val _screenState = MutableStateFlow<HomeUiState>(HomeUiState.Loading)
val screenState: StateFlow<HomeUiState> = _screenState

init {
   fetchHomeData()
}

private fun fetchHomeData() {
   _screenState.value = HomeUiState.Loading
   viewModelScope.launch {
       when (val homeData = homeUseCase.execute()) {
          is SimpleResult.Success -> {
              _screenState.value = HomeUiState.Success(homeData.value)
          }
          is SimpleResult.Error -> {
              _screenState.value = HomeUiState.Error(homeData.error)
          }
       }
    }
}
```

I am not able to figure out why it's not working.

Comment: Your provided code works fine for me. I think there is no issue in the provided code. There must be some task going on in Main/UI thread which blocks animation. Animation won't work if there is some operation on Main thread

Comment: Can you add more code? Actual code i mean

Comment: Added code where shimmer item is being called.

Comment: Can you provide viewmodel code too, when state is updated?

Comment: Updated with viewmodel code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for viewmodel code. As i said earlier that there is some ongoing task on MainThread!

You are executing homeUseCase on MainThread. Just need to use separate thread for executing homeUseCase and then animation will work fine.

Updated ViewModel code:

```
private fun fetchHomeData() {
   _screenState.value = HomeUiState.Loading
   viewModelScope.launch {
       withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
           when (val homeData = homeUseCase.execute()) {
              is SimpleResult.Success -> {
                  _screenState.value = HomeUiState.Success(homeData.value)
              }
              is SimpleResult.Error -> {
                  _screenState.value = HomeUiState.Error(homeData.error)
              }
           }
       }
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

When animations or UI rendering tasks are performed, they usually occur on the main thread, which is also known as the UI thread.

The main thread is responsible for handling UI rendering, user interactions, and animations, so any long-running or blocking operations executed on the main thread can lead to poor app performance, unresponsive UI, and animations that appear choppy or not working as expected.

Comment: Consider this as '+5 upvote' for the explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Shimmering is working in actual devices but not in emulator.

Comment: you can also pass the dispatcher to usecase using constructor injection. This way it is easier to test. You can also use    `viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {`